# How to remove the backslash added by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, visual-studio-2012

After downgrading from framework 4.5 to 4.0 I had to fix a lot of breakdowns. One of the things that changed was that Jquery started escaping double quotes. Is there anyway to disable that?

I tried  `datatest = datatest.replace("\\", "");` But that only works for the first backslash

What I want:

```
[
  { "on": "true", "length": "1" },
  { "on": "false", "length": "1" },
  { "on": "true", "length": "2" }
  ...
]
```

What I actually get:

```
[
  { \"on\": \"true\", \"length\": \"1\" },
  { \"on\": \"false\", \"length\": \"1\" },
  { \"on\": \"true\", \"length\": \"2\" }
  ...
]
```

Comment: I cannot see a difference between what you are getting and what you are wanting

Comment: What the difference??

Comment: What yoU See Is What yoU Get ;)

Comment: sorry forgot to add it in. you guys are fast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
datatest = datatest.replace(/\\/g, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither me but if you want to perform all the replaces it would be

```
datatest = datatest.replace(/\\g/, "");
```